# Placement of 'Window' menu group in Genero Studio 2.50.15

Tags: 4gl, genero

The manual says that [windowMenu](http://www.4js.com/online_documentation/fjs-fgl-manual-html/?path=fjs-fgl-manual#r_fgl_presentation_styles_window_style_attributes.html)

> Defines if the WCI container should display an automatic 'Window'
>   menu, with Cascade and Tile features, and list of child windows.
>   Values can be 'yes', 'no' (default).

Setting `<StyleAttribute name="windowMenu" value="yes" />` in the style file enables the 'Window' menu group.  The problem is that when a TopMenu is loaded the ‘Window’ menu group appears on the left of the other menu groups.  I want to be able to control the order of the menu groups and put the ‘Window’ menu group on the right-hand side of the other menu groups.  How do I implement that requirement?

[image: Screenshot showing placement of 'Window' menu group]